# How to pass function to another function that sets its completion closure?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Assuming we have the following method:

```
func searchLocation(keyword: String, completion: @escaping RequestResult<[Location])>)
```

where `RequestResult` is a typealias to `public typealias RequestResult<T> = (Result<T>) -> ()`

and another method:

```
func throttleRequest<T>(request: PLACEHOLDER, completion: @escaping RequestResult<[T]> {
    request { result in 
        print("Capturing some data") // do some stuff with the result in this scope
        completion(result)           // tell the caller the network function finsihed with `result`
    }
}
```

How should I modify the method signatures so I can do something like this:

```
throttleRequest(request: {
    searchLocation(keyword: "New York", completion: PLACEHOLDER)
}, 
completion: { result in
    if case .success(let found) = result {
       print("location found")
    }
})
```

so that the following gets printed:

```
$ Location found
$ Capturing some data
```

I've entered PLACEHOLDER above on some type definitions, since I can't really figure out what's proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's use a proper return type instead of `()` which is the same as `Void`. It's easier to read when you explicitly specify you're returning void instead of writing `()`. In any case, what you want is a lambda function parameter.

IE: You want a function that takes a lambda as an argument. 
Therefore:

```
public typealias RequestResult<T> = (Result<T, Error>) -> Void

func searchLocation(keyword: String, completion: RequestResult<[Location]>) {
    completion(.success([Location()]))
}

func throttleRequest<T>(request: (RequestResult<[T]>) -> Void, completion: @escaping RequestResult<[T]>) {
    request {
        print("Capturing some data")
        completion($0)
    }
}
```

So the syntax for a function/lambda as a parameter is:  `(ArgumentType...) -> ReturnType`

- `(Int) -> Void` is a function that takes an int, returns Void/nothing.
- `(T) -> U` is a function that takes a T argument and returns a U.

Likewise, if you want the parameter to be optional, then it is defined as:

`((Arguments...) -> ReturnType)?`

Usages:

```
throttleRequest(request: { result in
        self.searchLocation(keyword: "New York", completion: result)
    }, completion: { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let locations):
            print(locations)

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    })
```

Or easier to read (imo you make `_ request` the parameter):

```
throttleRequest({ self.searchLocation(keyword: "New York", completion: $0) }) {
        switch $0 {
        case .success(let locations):
            print(locations)

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is pretty close to where I got. Unfortunately, in your example where  you pass `result` in `searchLocation(keyword: completion:)`, the compiler is erroring with `"Passing non-escaping parameter 'result' to function expecting an @escaping closure"`, which I can't seem to work around.

Comment: Nvm, looks like `throttleRequest`  needs a double @escaping, one for the closure and one for the argument of the closure. I'd edit you answer to make it easier for future readers.

Comment: In my code, @Thanos; I made the parameter non-escaping. This compiles for me in Xcode 11.3.1. I did that so that I don't have to capture self in the `throttleRequest` parameter.